# Angularjs: parenthetically show negative numbers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to either:
1) filter currency numbers without any indication of which currency the number is (including a dollar sign; no symbols what-so-ever)?
2) filter regular numbers by showing negative numbers in parentheses?

E.g. -12.345 filtered would look like: (12.345)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The currency filter takes a symbol parameter. Set it to '' and it won't show a symbol. It'll show parentheses when negative...

```
{{ value | currency : '' }}
```

It will, however, round the number to 2 decimal places. You can easily create a custom filter...

```
app.filter('numeric', function() {
    return function (value) {
        if (value < 0) {
            value = '(' + Math.abs(value) + ')';
        }
        return value;
    };
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9zfg2/)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I modified the code to take a "sigfig" input so the # of decimals is configurable like with number. Also, wish I could upvote it, but I don't have enough reps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this filter to display a number with parenthesis instead of a minus sign:

```
angular.module('yourModule', [])
    .filter('negativeParenthesis', function() {
        return function(input) {
            if (input < 0) {
                return "("+Math.abs(input)+")";
            } else {
                return input + "";
            }
        }
    });
```

You would, of course, use it like so:

```
<p>{{myNumberValue|negativeParenthesis}}</p>
```